# Is it more efficient to put the entire function in a infinite loop with a time.Sleep at the end or loop a go routine?

Tags: go

I have a function that I want to poll every 20 seconds or so right now it's called in a go routine like so:

`go StartTradeBot()`

then in the body of the function:

```
func StartTradeBot() {
    for {
        // All the stuff to do
        time.Sleep(20 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

Is it more efficient like this?

or should I wrap my goroutine instead like

```
for {
    go StartTradeBot()
    time.Sleep(20 * time.Second)
}
```

Comment: This kind of question is rather subjective and is going to attract opinionated answers. That said, my opinion is that your function should do what it says on the lid, and if you need to sleep between running your bot, the caller should wait, not the `StartTradeBot()` function.

Comment: @AaronD Does that mean the second part of calling the goroutine would be your preference?

Comment: Yes. It makes the `StartTradeBot` function reusable without the built-in sleep call. That is, unless you *always* want to sleep as part of calling the bot function.

Comment: @AaronD Yeah its just a poll to see if any trades are active and it runs all the time

Comment: the two  do different things. the first one does ... waits until finished  and waits then 20 seconds , the second one starts the ... async, every 20 seconds. but the previous one could still be executing.

If you want to poll every 20 seconds, as you write, i'd do: `for range time.Tick(20*time.Second) {    // do stuff}`

Comment: Agreed with Adam - the fundamental question is why you wait? Also, have you considered the use of a channel to trigger the processing?

Comment: @AlessandroSantini Basically it's a bot that polls every 20 seconds to see if any new trades have came in, it polls a remote API provided by Steam I want it up and running as soon as my program starts

Comment: @Datsik I think it could get more complicated then - how critical is that you poll each 20 seconds? In the first case you will poll each 20 seconds + routine processing time; in the second case, if the processing takes more than 20 seconds, you may end up having two goroutines possibly contending resources because they run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three variations on how do this, each with different functionality. Because the interval is 20 seconds, the difference in performance is negligible. Pick the variation that best meets the application's functionality requirements.

Option 1: Pause 20 seconds between each operation.

```
for {
    // Do stuff
    time.Sleep(20 * time.Second)
}
```

Option 2: Start an operation every 20 seconds, even if previous operation is still executing.

```
for {
   go func() {
      // Do stuff
   }()
   time.Sleep(20 * time.Second)
}
```

Option 3: Start operation every 20 seconds or after previous operation completes, whichever is later.

```
t := time.NewTicker(20 * time.Second)
for range t.C {
   // Do stuff
}
```